# Flutter app as option to receive pdf from browser on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter, pdf, android-intent, open-with

I'm sorry if this question is stupid, but i'm a really beginner in IOS apps.

I'm using the package "receive_sharing_intent" to receive PDF files to my app, and it's working great when the file is loaded from the device or from Mail App.
The problem is when I try to receive the PDF direct from browser. My app isn't an option to open with.

Thanks in advance for the help.